# C++: Recursive Bisection Algorithm Keeps Returning 0

Tags: c++, recursion, bisection

I am trying to implement a Bisection Root Finding Algorithm from scratch, and the equation I am passing it is x^2 - 42 = 0. My code keeps giving the output "The root of 42 is 0 within an error of 1e-05. ", meaning that the recursion stack of my bisection algo keeps returning 0 for some reason. The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Bisection
{
public:

  double a;
  double b;
  double c;
  double epsilon;

  void set_values(double, double, double);

  double f(double x)
  {
    return x*x - 42;
  }

  double solve(double a, double b, double epsilon)
  {
    c = (a+b)/2.0;
    if(abs(f(c)) < epsilon)
    {
      return c;
    }
    else
    {
      if (f(a) * f(c) < 0.0)
      {
        b = c;
        solve(a, b, epsilon);
      }
      else if (f(c) * f(b) < 0.0)
      {
         a = c;
         solve(a, b, epsilon);
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
};

void Bisection::set_values(double left, double right, double error)
{
  a = left;
  b = right;
  epsilon = error;
}

int main()
{
  Bisection myObj;
  myObj.set_values(0.0, 10.0, 0.00001);
  //cout << myObj.f(7);
  cout << "The root of 42 is " << myObj.solve(myObj.a, myObj.b, myObj.epsilon) << " within     an error of " << myObj.epsilon << ".";
  return 0;
}
```

I had to include the "return 0;" line because my compiler was throwing back "non-void function does not return a value in all control paths" without it. How can I change my code to include a return value for all recursion paths but still yield the right answer? Is there an error in my fundamental design of the algorithm, or is it a simple fix?

Comment: `return solve(....`?

Comment: Firstly, there are members `a` and `b` and also parameters with the same name, which doesn't help. In any case, you could solve this yourself easily if you stepped through the code with a debugger. Try to find a nice video tutorial explaining how to do that with your IDE, it's a very useful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other problems with the code aside, you need to actually do something with the result of `solve`. Usually this means `return`ing the result from `solve` directly until you reach the base case and return that:

```cpp
double solve(double a, double b, double epsilon)
{
    c = (a+b)/2.0;
    if(abs(f(c)) < epsilon)
    {
      return c; //this is your base case
    }
    else
    {
      if (f(a) * f(c) < 0.0)
      {
        b = c;
        return solve(a, b, epsilon);
      }
      else if (f(c) * f(b) < 0.0)
      {
         a = c;
         return solve(a, b, epsilon);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: @arnavlohe15 Please mark it as Accepted. :)